# Show UIActivityIndicator while drawing in Quartz

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, core-graphics

I have a complex Quartz routine in `drawRect` for a custom `UIView` subclass. It can take a few seconds to draw. What I'd like is to show a `UIActivityIndicator` while it is drawing. But then the indicator must stop spinning (and get hidden) after the drawing is complete.

I tried to start the animation of the indicator and then use `performSelector` for a custom method that simply calls `setNeedsDisplay` - my thinking is that `performSelector` will wait until the next run loop, right? In which case, my indicator has time to start on the main thread. This seems to be working, but as soon as I add the code to the end of `drawRect` to stop the animation, the indicator doesn't show up at all, as if this animation is ending before it's had a chance to begin.

Any suggestions?

I call the drawing like this:

```
[self.spinner startAnimating];
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(redraw) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];//tried both YES and NO here

-(void)redraw{
[self.customView setNeedsDisplay];
```

}

The `drawRect:` simply has this at the end:

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
  //bunch of drawing
  [self.nav stopSpinner]; // reference to a controller class
   }
```

In `self.nav` object is this:

```
 -(void)stopSpinner{
self.spinner.hidden=YES;
[self.spinner stopAnimating];
}
```

And the `spinner` object is initially created like this:

```
    self.spinner=[[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge]autorelease];
    self.spinner.hidden=YES;
    [self.viewController.view addSubview:self.spinner];
```

Comment: Show us the `drawRect:` code that tries to stop the spinning.

Comment: it's quite long and I'd rather not post it here; however the very last line before the function's `}` is the message to the `UIActivityIndicator` for it to stop animating.

Comment: Edit your question and paste in that line.

Comment: i found the issue and will be updating my question in a sec. the problem with the spinner not stopping is that I forgot to pass reference to the right object for `self.nav` but now the indicator is not showing up at all, likely because the drawing is still happening on the same run loop event as the indicator starts animating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform your drawing on a background thread. Not only will this allow you to throw up an activity indicator and have it animate as desired, but the drawing itself with be much much faster. In my tests, I've seen a speed increase of 10X in complex Quartz drawing on a background thread.

And it's not hard. In fact, it might be so fast you won't need the activity indicator.

Here's the code, and you can simply use a regular `UIImageView` and then assign its `image` property to the rendered output from the other thread:

```
 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

  dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //perform some drawing into this context

    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.imageView.image=viewImage;
    });
});
```